# How we can construct Turing Machine for a^n b^(nm) for n,m > 0

Tags: computer-science

How we can construct a Turing Machine for language L = {a^n b^nm where n>0). I couldn't understand the part of n.m part for designing.

Answer (score 0):

Stack overflow doesn't do your homework for you.

But to give you at least a start.  Try writing a TM that does the following:

0. Make sure the string is of the form `a+b*`.
1. If there are no more `b`s, then succeed.
2. For each `a` at the start of the string, delete a `b` at the end of the string.
3. If you run out of `b`s in the middle of deleting them, then fail
4. Otherwise, go back to step 1.